# Thread and socket programming

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse

I need to see some example of threads using sockets to send and receive a message. I am almost new to it.I google it but there was no useful and simple example for beginners. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: What platform/language? .Net, C# or VB.Net ...???

Comment: Provide a bit of extra information about what you have tried - doesn't matter if it is working ...helps get an idea of what you've tried, and where your mistakes are.

Comment: As I said before I am totally beginner I want to have some threads sending data to each other.  There is socket connection between them.

Comment: Attack one at a time.  Either study tutorials about threading or tutorials about socket programming (without threads).  Once you geta good understanding of one, you'll be better equipped to understand the tutorials that try to teach you to use leverage both together.

Answer (score 6):

[java sockets@oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Comment: +1 a tutorial is always a good place to start. This is the link I was going to give.

Comment: You really should provide some sort of specifics ...something that will keep this answer relevant whether the link is available or not.

Comment: @IAbstract, We don't have the time or space to provde specifics on how socket programming works. The tutorial is the place to start until the poster can ask specific questions. This is an Oracle link that has been around for a decade and there is no need to duplicate the information here.

Comment: @camickr - so you know nothing that will help out the OP, or personal experiences to draw from? ...see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13369/is-it-okay-to-answer-a-stackoverflow-question-with-a-link/13370#13370