# How to override a loop fetching messages in a method

Tags: java, arraylist, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth server receiving data from a client, a mobile phone. The code I'm using looks the following

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        this.localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        this.localDevice.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);

        this.server = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(URL);

        while(true) {
            if(this.connection == null) {
                this.connection = this.server.acceptAndOpen();

                System.out.println("INFO: Bluetooth client connected");

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.openInputStream()));
                this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.openOutputStream()));

                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(line.equals("--#do:disconnect")) {
                        break;
                    }

                    System.out.println("INFO: Received from Bluetooth: " + line);
                }

                System.out.println("INFO: Client disconnected");
            }
        }
    } catch(BluetoothStateException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an infinitive loop receiving messages until it is told to stop. At the moment the loop receives all the messages. There is a problem with that. The class where the code is used is a model class in MVC. In the class I also have a method called `getContacts()`. It is used to receive contacts from the phone over Bluetooth. The phone is told to send the contacts when the server sends `--#do:getcontacts`.

What I need to do is to get the contacts in an ArrayList in the `getContacts()` method and return it as the return value of the method so that the controller can handle the contacts.

```
public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    // How do I get the contacts in the ArrayList?

    return contacts;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just make the contacts a field of whatever class this is in? Access to it could then be done using "return Collections.unmodifiableList(contacts)".

Comment: I would suggest not limiting your class/methods to a particular implementation type.  I would recommend using the List interface instead.

Comment: Would you show what you mean? I didn't really get it...

Comment: Are you saying the getContacts() method and the run() method are in the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll have you some suggestions. My examples are no working code, just a working base for you.

First, I strongly suggest you to use threads in a server. Everytime a clients connects to the server, you create a new thread, with parameters containing all data needed to start it:

```
boolean running = true;    //this class variable will allow you to shut down the server correctly

public void stopServer(){    //this method will shut down the server
    this.running = false;
}

public void run() {
    ...

    while(running) {
        // if(this.connection == null) {  // I removed this line since it's unnecessary, or even harmful!
        StreamConnection connection = this.server.acceptAndOpen();  //This line will block until a connection is made...
        System.out.println("INFO: Bluetooth client connected");
        Thread thread = new ServerThread(connection);
        thread.start()              //don't forget exception handling...
    } 
}
```

And in the class ServerThread you implement these lines handling the clients (non-compiled code, without exception handling!):

```
Class ServerThread extends Thread {
    StreamConnection connection;

    public ServerThread(StreamConnection connection){
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public void run() {
        ...

        connection.close();     //closing the connection...don't forget exception handling!
        System.out.println("INFO: Client disconnected");
    }
}
```

What is the advantage of this code? Your server is now able to handle a thousand clients at the same moment. You've got parallelisation, and that's how server usually work! A server without threads is like socks without shoes...

Second, if you have a Java client and a Java server, you can use a much easier way to send your objects to the server: ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream. You just send the array (I'll use an ArraList as it would be usual) containing the contacts to the server, and then you read the array. Here is the code for the server (again uncompiled and without any exception handling):

```
Class ServerThread extends Thread {
    StreamConnection connection;

    public ServerThread(StreamConnection connection){
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public void run() {

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(this.connection.openInputStream());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);

        ArrayList contacts = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();  //this is a cast: don't forget exception handling!
        //You could also try the method ois.readUTF(); especially if you wanna use other non-Java clients

        System.out.println("INFO: Received from Bluetooth: " + contacts);
        this.connection.close();    //closing the connection...don't forget exception handling!
        //ois.close();      //do this instead of "this.connection.close()" if you want the connection to be open...i.e. to receive more data

        System.out.println("INFO: Client disconnected");

        //here you do whatever you wanna do with the contacts array, maybe add to your other contacts?
    }
}
```

In Java, every class is an object, including ArrayList. And since the end of the object will be regarded as the disconnection, you won't need to do anything else.

Third: You use above server not only for bluetooth connections, but also for WLAN connections, aso. Then you could easily start different threads, like in pseudo code `if(connection.isBluetooth()){//create a thread from BluetoothThread} else if(connection.isWLAN()){//create a thread from WLANsThread}`. I don't know what your app is about, but maybe one day you would like to expand it to desktop PC, so using WLAN would be the right thing. Also because you anyway need to build in a verification in the client ("which contacts are going to be sent to which server?"), no matter if it's bluetooth or WLAN, because the low range of buetooth can't give you any security. ;)

Fourth, finally about your question: To get something, you need to have a data source and/or a class variable. Here a short example with a file that stores the contacts (but it could also be a database...local or somewhere else!):

```
public class MyApp(){
    ArrayList contacts;
    ...

    public void run(){                  //this happens when we start our app
        this.contacts = new ArrayList();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader ("C:\WhereverYourFileIs\Contacts.file");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        //here you use a loop to read the contacts via "br" from the file and fill them into your array...I can't provide you more code, since the exact data structure is up to you.
    }

    //now we want to send our contacts array to the already connected server:
    public sendArrayToServer() {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream (this.connection.openOutputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(this.contacts);
         //If you use readUTF() in the server, you need to call here something like oos.writeUTF(this.contacts.toString()); or even need to use another parser method which exactly creates the string you want.
        this.connection.close();    //closing the connection...don't forget exception handling!
        //oos.close();      //do this instead of "this.connection.close()" if you want the connection to stay open...
    }
}
```

Now in the server you just read out the contacts array as already I described above. What you do with those contacts, remains up to you.

Hope this helps you to understand your problems and find a solution. Programming is all about trial & error..and improving your code.

**EDIT:**

After our discussion I finally found out what you need: You need a one-thread server called BluetoothManager that interacts with another thread called GUIController. Now since I anyway did the implementation in my head, I can post it for you, together with some explanations. Just note that in this case you don't need to initialize another thread in the server, since the BluetoothManager is already a thread, and you anyway need only one connection at the same moment (the question remains, if that is a "server", I would rather call it a "receiver"):

```
Public class BluetoothManager extends Thread{
    boolean running = true;    //this class variable will allow you to shut down the server correctly
    GUIController controller;

    public BluetoothManager(GUIController controller){
        this.controller = controller;  //this registers the GUIController in the BluetoothManager
    }

    public void stop(){    //this method will shut down the "server"
        this.running = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        this.localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        this.localDevice.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
        this.server = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(URL);
        while(running){
            StreamConnection connection = this.server.acceptAndOpen();  //This line will block until a connection is made...or running==false!
            System.out.println("INFO: Bluetooth client connected");
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(this.connection.openInputStream());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            ArrayList contacts = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();  //this is a cast: don't forget exception handling!
            System.out.println("INFO: Received from Bluetooth: " + contacts);
            this.connection.close();    //closing the connection...don't forget exception handling!
            System.out.println("INFO: Client disconnected");
            this.controller.refreshContacts(contacts);
        }
    } 
}

public class GUIController extends Thread implements Runnable {
    ArrayList contacts;   //also a HashMap may be appropriate
    BluetoothManager manager;

    public void run(){
        this.contacts = new ArrayList();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader ("C:\WhereverYourFileIs\Contacts.file");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        //here you use a loop to read the contacts via "br" from the file and fill them into your array...I can't provide you more code, since the exact data structure is up to you.
    }

    public void startBluetoothManager(){    //starting the BluetoothManager
        this.manager = new BluetoothManager(this);
        this.manager.start();
    }

    public void abortBluetoothManager(){  //call this when clicking on the "Abort" button
        this.manager.stop();
        //now the next 2 lines you normally don't need...still may use it if you've problems shutting down the thread:
        // try{ this.manager.interrupt(); }   //we want to be 100% sure to shut down our thread!
        // catch(Exception e){}
        this.manager = null; //now the garbage collector can clean everything...byebye
    }

    public void refreshContacts(ArrayList contacts) {
        // synchronize(this.contactArray){  //no synchronisation needed if you have a GUI pop-up with an "Abort"-button!
        Iterator i = this.contacts.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            this.contacts.add(i.next());
        }
        //At the end you need remove the "Receiving message" pop-up together with the "Abort Receiving"-button, these are all class variables!
        // important note: If you have unique entries, you may need to replace them! In this case I suggest storing all contact objects better in a HashMap contacts, and use the unique ID as a key to find the element. And then you may prompt the user, if there are identical entries, to overwrite each entry or not. These things remain all up to you.
    }
}
//As always: This is no compiled code!!
```

The GUIController first runs the BluetoothManager with `startBluetoothManager()` and does nothing else, except showing a notification "Receiving contacts" and an "Abort Reveiving"-button. And when the BluetoothManager is finished, he just adds the new contacts into the existing contacts-array inside the GUIController by calling `refreshContacts(...)`. If you push the "Abort Reveiving"-button, you immediately call the `abortBluetoothManager()` method, which sets `running=false` in the BluetoothManager to end the server and finish the thread.

The main problem this solution solves: It's not possible for two threads to directly communicate with each other! Once you call `thread.start()`, every thread is on its own. That's why there is no possibility for the BluetoothManager-thread to tell the GUIController-thread "I've finished!". The only thing those threads can do, is share the same ressource(s), and communicate via this ressource(s). In our case, it's the `contacts`-ArrayList in the GUIController, which first I thought needs to be synchronized and can be updated by both threads (but not on the same time). And - kind of funnyness - there is a second shared ressource, it's actually the `running` flag in the class BluetoothManager which can shut it down (but there is never any synchronisation of `running` needed, this variable is only changed by the GUIController).

Now about the synchronisation: I thought about this problem more and understood, that you can solve your problem also *without* any "synchronized(...)" call. So, if you don't want to synchronize the ArrayList, you must do it like this: While the server is running, you only show the "Receiving Contacts" pop-up and the "Abort Reveiving"-button. While this happens, you just never access the contact-ArrayList inside the GUIController. This is somehow an "intrinsic synchronisation" which needs no real Java synchronisation. Still you may implement synchronisation, just to be 100% sure that nothing happens if you expand the app in the future.

Comment: Really nice answer. You gave me something to think about. My app is about using a computer to send text messages trough a mobile phone, so no need for multiple connections. That's why the server side is implemented that way. Maybe in the future I'll expand it to use WLAN as one option as well but I'll stick with this for now. Your idea of using ObjectOutputStream is great! But can I use ObjectOutputStream side by side with the current solution? The program is supposed to be able to send clear data as well. Or do you think I should send strings as objects as well?

Comment: Is the client (the computer) a Java app as well? Or is it rather a C-app (C++/C-Objective)? If it's a Java client: Yes, you could send any Java object with `ObjectOutputStream`, also a Java string (you can look in the Java API which method of the class ObjectOutput/InputStream fits your requirements). If it's a no-Java client: You could try to get the job done with the encoding/method `readUFT()` from `ObjectInputStream`. Or another method from another InputStream class...it just depends on what kind of data the clients sends, so you could run a few tests to find out which method works. ;)

Comment: Yes, both the client and the server are written in Java. I know I can send strings over ObjectOutputStream but I just wonder if that's good or not.

Comment: I don't know if this works for you, you must do the testing by yourself. However, if you are planing to expand your app to C++/C-Objective clients, you better don't touch the client and only use an appropriate parser-method in the class `ObjectInputStream` to create the "sink object" on the server. It's always good to program such interfaces plattform independent.

Comment: Or you check out the method `writeUTF(String str)` in the class `ObjectOutputStream` and analyse exactly what kind of strings it creates, so you could create similar strings for future C++/C-Objective clients. Therefore you may need to store a written UTF in a file once, and analyse how it looks like, and think about if you could create such an UTF also with other programming languages.

Comment: I'm not really looking forward to expand the program to handle C++ clients because the client is supposed to run on Android and it works just fine with Java. Please, see my comment below iTech's answer.

Comment: Just said: I'm going to clean the last 2 commentaries after you've read it, because it's off-topic. ;) Well, here's the solution implemented more in details: `public class BluetoothManager{ GUIController controller; public BluetoothManager(GUIController controller){ this.controller = controller }`...and then you call in the BluetoothManager after you've received the contacts from the client: `this.controller.refreshContacts(contacts)`

Comment: Thanks for your comments again. Isn't it 'illegal' to let the model class to call controller in MVC structure? Otherwise that would be easy to do but will it cause mess?

Comment: Your welcome. I wrote this already in the other comment at the bottom: *"If GUI controller and the BluetoothManager are [in] different threads, you need to synchronize before you update your contacts in the GUI Controller [...] But if they both run in the same thread, you won't need to synchronize [...]"* Anyway using different threads needs more care if you want to do write access, and you need to do this with the "synchronize(...)"-command in Java. But if you are running only one thread, you won't need to synchronize. Also an usual read access (e.g. on ArrayList) won't need synchronization

Comment: Actually, I've just looked once more into your BluetoothManager and saw the `run()`-method, and since you mentioned also a GUIController, it's clear that you have 2 threads. This is alright, since the GUIController could call a method `stopServer()` to end the server. However, in Java a thread means always a sequential processing for its own, so you never have to worry about dependencies between objects, you can call everytime whatever you want. The only problem is when you access/change variables. This link will help you to learn more: http://www.google.ch/search?q=java+thread+synchronized

Comment: Yesterday I just posted 10 another comments and soon realized, that I can't teach you how to do multihreading. ;-) However, for your app it's okey if you do just the following thing: Everywhere you access (read or write!) the contacts-array in the GUI or GUIController or somewhere else, you just call a `synchronized(contactsArray) {...`. And as I already said you need to implement the method `refreshContacts(ArrayList contacts){...` into the GUIController, where you add the new contacts to your contactsArray. Then your programm works always correctly and you don't need to mess more with that.

Comment: And if you want to do multithreading in the future, I really suggest to learn Sockets first (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303141/thread-and-socket-programming). Once you know the Sockets, you can start with useful links like this: google.ch/search?q=java+thread+synchronized, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html, http://www.roseindia.net/java/thread/SynchronizedThreads.shtml. Anyhow, when it comes to thread programming, there are more dont's than do's: Never use Collections.synchronizedList since you anyway need to synchronize the shared objects...

Comment: ...by yourself (docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), never use synchronized methods (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), never use volatile (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), be aware of starvation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html) and deadlocks (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html). But you should also know that a person must be quite stupid to create deadlocks in Java, the person must run different code..

Comment: ...doing opposite things (like thread1 locks objectA and waits for objectB, while thread2 locks objectB and waits for objectA), and this behaviour usually won't occur because you'll rather create different instances of the same class and therefore calling/blocking the objects always in the same order. Even more you must use Iterator to handle ArrayLists (http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/collections/arraylist/index.html, http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/collections/arraylist/listiterator.html, docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), and to deeper understand...

Comment: ...deeper understand what `synchronized(object)` really does, you need to read articles like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html. Actually, `synchronized(object)` first calls kind of "wait(object)" and when the object is free it calls a `notifyAll()` to free all waiting threads (but then only one thread can access the object at once). While both method can be found in the Java class `Object` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). That's the overhead you always create while initializing any object in Java (basic values...

Comment: ...like `int` don't have it). However, now you may also just start over reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html, or you just try once to implement a Socket server with some Threads: Learning by doing. ;)

Comment: One more thing about deadlocks: They can only occur if you create nested synchronized-blocks, that's calling `synchronized(object)` of *different* objects right after each other. That's anyway not suggested if you don't really need it, you should only lock one object at once in the code. In the other hand, starvation occurs only in high performance systems, because the closing `}` after every synchronized block will free the object automatically. Using synchronized means just using the built-in lock of Java, nothing more. It's amazing how Java is natively designed to do multithreading.

Comment: And since in the software world there are often several words for the same thing, the flag that locks an object is also called "monitor": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Implicit_condition_variable_monitors. "Monitor", that's actually just "owning the flag" ;) And why I suggested never to use synchronized methods but synchronized (b)locks: Many performance measurements had shown that using synchronized blocks is best (and it's always better if the controller decides where there is synchronisation needed, not the object by itself, since it can be done in 1 line of code!).

Comment: So, to summarize it: In java, you can do multihreading very easily with only 4 lines. 2 lines of starting any thread `Thread thread1 = new Thread();` and `thread1.start();` in one hand, and lock the objects before manipulation with `synchronized(object){` and then free them with `}` again. So the only complicated thing is to know when you need to lock objects and when not. To say it in one sentence: Only changing a variable of an object or the structure of an array needs locks. But it's also possible to lock always if you access the object (also reads), and that's what I suggested you above.

Comment: Now I wrote another 10 commentaries, *lol*. I really need to stop now. Multihreading in Java is a very cool thing...ones you've understood how to do it. %)

Comment: It's nice to see someone investing in their answers a lot. Though I think there has been some misunderstanding between us. I know how threads are supposed to be used (and yes, they are running in different threads!) but I was just wondering if I can tell the controller class to wait until the BluetoothManager class has received the contacts.

Comment: Allright, but if want to you use (the advantage of) threads, you can't make them wait. A waiting thread is for nothing, then you could use just 1 thread to do the job. What you must do: You print the user a pop-up with an abort-button. So you are "waiting" in the GUIController for a possible abort-I/O, but this is no real (thread) waiting. Even more, if you want that abort-button, you can't let the GUIController wait, it needs to have an active listener! So you need to have two running threads: BluetoothManager (the running server) and GUIController (which listens to the button).

Comment: However, I updated my answer now, giving you the solution that you are searching.

Comment: A bit late but thanks for the answer. I awarded you the bounty but I'm not sure should I mark it as an answer - yet.. In your example the model class calls the controller. Normally in MVC this shouldn't be what you are doing so just wondering if there's something else you could do. In my opinion the model should be independent of the controller.

Comment: Ah, you must have something gotten wrong. The classes BluetoothManager and GUIController are both controller, and the models are always data structures like the ArrayList contacts or the class Contact. The models are the data which is sent between controllers. It's possible to use specifically designed classes as model (like "Contact", "Message", or whatever), or you use a more generic class like HashMap (these are associative arrays, the same as PHP "arrays" or Javascript "objects"). The line `this.manager = new BluetoothManager(this)` just means that a controller creates another controller.

Comment: Thanks! (and something to meet the requirements on message length...)

Answer (score 2):

First of all there are few things in you code need to be reviewed/fixed

1- the `ArrayList<Contact> contacts` should be defined in your class, so the thread can have access to it and populate it **not** as a local variable within `getContacts()` method

```
public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {

    //ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();    

    return contacts;
}
```

2- You should avoid using *infinite* loop within the run method to be able to stop the thread when you want to.

```
//while(true)
while(isRunning) { // a flag that is set to true by default

}
```

3- Checking that the connection equal *without* setting it to null after disconnecting means that the connection will be accepted **only** from the first client (assuming that connection is originally set to null) and afterwards your will just have an infinite loop but the code `this.connection = this.server.acceptAndOpen();` will not be reachable anymore

```
if(this.connection == null) {               
  while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     if(line.equals("--#do:disconnect")) {
           // You have to set it to null if you want to continue listening after disconnecting
           this.connection = null
           break;
      }
   }
 }
```

Or simply **remove this check altogether**, I see it is useless.

Now back to your question:

You can define your contact list as a class member to be accessible by both `run()` and `getContacts()` methods. You can make it final if needed. Then populate this list within the `run()` method; that's all.

e.g.

```
 class MyServerThread implements Runnable {
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts(){
        // Make sure that your not currently updating the contacts when this method is called
        // you can define a boolean flag and/or use synchronization
        return contacts;
    }

    public void run() {

     ...

    while(isRunning ) {
            this.connection = this.server.acceptAndOpen();

            System.out.println("INFO: Bluetooth client connected");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.openInputStream()));
            this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.openOutputStream()));

            // You need to remove previously received contacts before issuing a new --#do:getcontacts command                
            contacts.clear();

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.equals("--#do:disconnect")) {
                    break;
                }

                // Here you can parse the contact information
                String contactName = ...
                String contactPhone = ...
                contacts.add(new Contact(contactName,contactPhone));
            }

            System.out.println("INFO: Client disconnected");            
    }
} catch(BluetoothStateException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
  }

 }
```

You do not have to use Object serialization, you can construct a simple protocol to send contacts from the phone to the PC, something similar to the commands you send e.g. `--#C:name$phone`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good notes. You are receiving the contacts in the while loop which isn't ideal. Now they are received at the startup but it has to receive them when the user wants to. Of course I could tell the phone to re-send them. But because the GUI class calls controller class' method `refreshContacts()` which then calls `getContacts()` of `BluetoothManager` class, I need to get the contact list fully updated as the return value. If the loop is still fetching the contacts, how do I tell the rest of the parts to wait for the contacts to be downloaded?

Comment: Just use a `boolean flag` to indicate that the contact fetching is in progress i.e. set it to `true` when you start reading the contacts and set it to `false` at the end (better in a final block)

Comment: First of all I suppose that your GUI controller and the BluetoothManager are running in different threads. However, with a flag you still need to implement come kind of `while(true)`-loop in the GUI controller always checking the `getContacts()` and then calling `thread.sleep(...)` or a `synchronized(this){this.wait(...);}`, which I don't recommend at all. It's much easier if you instantiate `BluetoothManager(GUIController controller)` and then you call in the BluetoothManager: `this.controller.refreshContacts(contacts)`. That's how object dependencies are usually done in Java.

Comment: Ah, I almost forgot to say, If GUI controller and the BluetoothManager are different threads, you need to synchronize before you update your contacts in the GUI Controller: `class GUIController{ ArrayList contactArray; ....... public refreshContacts(ArrayList contacts) { synchronize(this.contactArray){/*here you add the contacts to the contactArray, they're actually both arrays, I just used different names to be clear*/}`. But if they both run in the same thread, you won't need to synchronize the contactArray before editing it (and: reading an ArrayList doesn't need synchronisation!).

Comment: I gave you +1 too because you showed some very good fixes to my code.